# What's the meaning of "Event" from Android Monkey Test report?

Tags: android, testing, monkey

from the report of Android Monkey Test.

```
Event percentages:
  0: 15.0%
  1: 10.0%
  2: 15.0%
  3: 25.0%
  4: 15.0%
  5: 2.0%
  6: 2.0%
  7: 1.0%
  8: 15.0%
```

What's the exactly meaning of 0-8 ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpfull to add some more background? I might know what is what, but might not. As is, I have no clue what a Monkey Test is, or how. And why. Also, `~~!!` needed? not so much.

Comment: Monkey testing is a standard tool in Android. You may not have heard of it, but you should not vote down a question based on your own ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer 
  0: 15.0% touch
  1: 10.0% motion
  2: 15.0% traceback
  3: 25.0% syskeys
  4: 15.0% nav
  5: 2.0%  majornav
  6: 2.0%  appswitch
  7: 1.0%  flip
  8: 15.0% anyevent

Answer (score 3):

Nowdays, Android Monkey Test writing more information about your running test (you can specify more options for run your test).

Example of run with all provide options:

```
./adb.exe shell monkey -p your.package.name --pct-touch 1 --pct-motion 2 --pct-pinchzoom 3 --pct-trackball 4 --pct-rotation 5 --pct-nav 6 --pct-majornav 7 --pct-syskeys 8 --pct-appswitch 9 --pct-flip 10 --pct-anyevent 45 --throttle 500 -v 50
```

Monkey write something like this (added appropriate switcher):

```
// Event percentages:
//   0: 1.0%    (--pct-touch 1)         
//   1: 2.0%    (--pct-motion 2)        
//   2: 3.0%    (--pct-pinchzoom 3)     
//   3: 4.0%    (--pct-trackball 4)     
//   4: 5.0%    (--pct-rotation 5)      
//   5: 6.0%    (--pct-nav 6)           
//   6: 7.0%    (--pct-majornav 7)      
//   7: 8.0%    (--pct-syskeys 8)       
//   8: 9.0%    (--pct-appswitch 9)     
//   9: 10.0%   (--pct-flip 10)         
//   10: 45.0%  (--pct-anyevent 45)
```

Many options are explain here: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html

And you sould wiew grap code here: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/109282209/